# How to make a copy of files from internal memory using adb in recovery mode? (S4, usb debugging is turned off, stock recovery)

Tags: adb, backup, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-4, boot-loop

My S4 doesn't turn on and unfortunately I didn't back up my files :-(

I only have access to recovery and download mode.

Is it possible to backup the files from my S4 using adb in the recovery mode? Or some other method?

I've tried to do it, but when I type the command `adb devices`, function in a console doesn't output any connected device. If in the recovery mode I select `apply update from adb` when I type `adb devices`, the function returns:

> List of devices attached
>   5f1e329c Sideload

But after entered the command `adb pull /` in a console function shows the message `error: closed`.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Use download mode to flash a device compatible  custom recovery. Afterwards, boot into recovery mode and use adb to do whatever you want.